# VBScript Outlook Form How do I set the To Field based off the value of a ComboBox?

Tags: forms, vbscript, combobox, outlook

I'm using Outlook 2007 and trying to design a form that changes the To: field based on whatever is in a ComboBox1.

Simple right? I thought so, until I found the documentation extremely lacking. Everything is point me to VBScrip and I have googled to exhaustion on the topic of setting the to field in vbscript.

Can someone with some outlook vbscript please write up a OnChange event to change the TO field of outlook after the combobox1 selection has been made?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Outlook uses VBA as its native language, not VBScript. If you are working within Outlook you will find a lot of examples using VBA. Sue Mosher is most helpful.

Comment: Outlook form uses VBScript. This is right from Sue Mosher's website. 

"The code behind Microsoft Outlook forms is always written with the Microsoft Visual Basic Scripting Engine, better known as VBScript, a small portable language, which is also used in web pages and standalone scripts."

Answer (score 0):

You know, I'm just going to forget coding the form and use HTA. At least when I create the Object I can setup the fields somewhat easier.